# Why Facebook user details are not coming?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am doing simple facebook login using latest facebook sdk 4.8 but after login i am getting null value no user details are coming but only i am getting the details if the user is developer and administrator of that Facebook App.

And also i have given facebook permission.

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_likes",
            "user_friends", "email", "user_birthday", "user_photos", "user_about_me"));

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    try{
                      nameTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      nameTxt.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("FacebookException", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,gender,birthday,email,bio,photos{link}");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched your app status to live? You can see status in your app's Dashboard in developers console.
 [image: Verify live status]

If not, just switch status to live in Status & Review tab. This switch should be switched to 'Yes' position [image: This switch should be switched to 'Yes' position]

Comment: yes it's live and Api version is 2.4 but still it's only showing the developer details not showing other regular facebook users.

Comment: Make sure Package Name and Key Hashes, which you can find in Settings->Android are correct. Please notice that for debug build you probably use other signature file than for release.

Comment: do we need to use different hash key for debug and release mode...??

Comment: You can find all the details in the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash


`When publishing your app, it is typically signed with a different signature to your development environment. Therefore, you want to make sure you create a Release Key Hash and add this to the Android settings for Facebook App ID.`

I recommend reading this 'Getting Started' guilde entirely. ;)